# Building modutils from source:error cannot find sources (insmod/insmod.c) in /usr/bin or

Tags: ubuntu, build

I tried installing the prerequisites for the modutils-2.4.27 package, but it just won't configure! I'm using Ubuntu but building this package from source, as I don't see it in apt-cache.

the configure script isn't generating any output; no config.log and no makefile.

bashdb trips on the following error:

cannot find sources (insmod/insmod.c) in /usr/bin or ..

not sure what to do.

Comment: Did you use this [version](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/modutils/v2.4/modutils-2.4.27.tar.gz) of modutils ? 
If yes, you should run `./configure` then `make` then `make install` in your terminal.
Otherwise, try to enable main repository in your Software center then `sudo apt-get update` then`sudo apt-get install build-essential`.
Finally check again if you can compile modutils from sources.

Comment: the ./configure script fails without any output, config.log or makefile. I have build-essential already installed. I used a debugger on configure (bashdb) and it produces the error message above.

Comment: Yes I did, before running a debugger on it. I made sure all deps are met according to the modutils website.